# Laravel: send pivot data to the client

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, orm, laravel-8

I'm working on a project using Laravel 8 where I have the following models and relationship:

[image]

A **Demand** belongs to a **Location** and a **Function**. On the front-end the user have drop downs and they can choose a function and a location.
The functions and locations are connected with a many to many relationship. I need to store an extra value on the pivot table:
[image]

I need to store the cost in the pivot table because a function can have different costs for each location. I know how to send the cost using pivot methods:

```
 public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Location ::class)->withPivot('hourly_rate')->using(LocationProfunctionPivot::class);
    }
```

When a users select a Function I send all the available locations and I managed to send the hourly_rate.
How can I send the cost after the user saved the demand? Because now the function and the location are sent separately.

Thank you!

**Update 1:** added the DemandResource class:

```
class DemandResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'function' => new ProfunctionResource($this->whenLoaded('function')),
            'location' => new LocationResource($this->whenLoaded('location')),
        ];
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Yqi.png
```

Comment: Still missing the cost part ! what I can understand is you need to append cost attribute in your Pivot Model, so when you save the function you will load also the pivot with it and the pivot is already has cost appended (`getCostAttribute(){ // do ur calculation }`)

Comment: @PsyLogic, When the demand is loading the function and location are sent as sperated entities. I updated the answert with the Demand Resource class

Comment: @PsyLogic, I just realized that what I need is to retrieve the pivot Model because I have the function id and the location id

Comment: Yes, that is right and both of them has the same pivot with additional columns and attribute (cost) that you add it in your Model and PivotModelResource